# how to add checkbox in select option in php?

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, checkbox

I make a php page i want to attach check box with list box option value how i attached checkbox,here is my code:

```
<select name="recepients[]" multiple size="10" multiple="multiple" >
     <?
        //echo $eventid=$_POST['events'];
        $count=count($_POST['events']);
        for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
            $select="select b.first_name,b.last_name from buyers b,registrations r where b.buyer_id=r.buyer_id and r.event_id='".$_POST['events'][$i]."' group by r.buyer_id";
            $res = $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($select) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);
            if ($res->num_rows > 0)
            {           
                while($row = $res->fetch_assoc ())
                {
                ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="receptionts[]" checked="checked"/> 
                <option value="<?=$row['first_name']?>"><?=$row['last_name']?></option>
                <?
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "attach"?

Comment: i mean option value has checkbox whose always selected

Comment: So you want to have an option selected by default?

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: echo `$select` and run the output in your sql server

Comment: i edit my code see my code then you get idea which i want

Comment: Is this because you are having trouble getting multiple options to be selected within your select (without holding ctrl while clicking the options)?

Comment: how can you create check box inside select?

Comment: i just want to attach checked check box with option value

Comment: do you want checkbox within dropdown like http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/05/how-to-make-multiple-select-dropdown-list-jquery.html

Comment: You can not put an <input> tag into a select. That is not allowed in html.
You should consider the solution of @kumar_v .

Comment: Do you want checkbox inside select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the principle of putting a checkbox in a list.
If this is to select all default item, you may use the lists multipe with the `selected` option on the option tags

```
<select multiple size="10">
...
    <option selected="selected" value="<?=$row['first_name']?>"><?=$row['last_name']?></option>
....
```

good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can make a field in your database that contains `selected=selected` if you want it selected. Then `echo $row['selected']`

Comment: but i don't make any field in database another solution will be prefered